# An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the ExportImage operation: The given S3 object is not local to the region

Tags: amazon-s3, virtual-machine, amazon-ami

I want to export a copy of my Amazon Machine Image (AMI) as a virtual machine (VM) to deploy in my on-site virtualization environment.

I Follow the steps mentioned in the link below

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-export-vm-using-import-export/

While running the export image command as below

aws ec2 export-image --image-id ami-id --disk-image-format VMDK --s3-export-location S3Bucket=my-export-bucket,S3Prefix=exports/

I encountered S3 Object not local to the region error. I checked My S3 Bucket and AMI both are in the same region.

What could be the solution to this error? I try changing AMI and Buckets but did'nt work

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your AWS config file? If it has a different region, then that might be the issue.

Location:

Home_Directory/.aws/config

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."